# Make python 2.7 the default python in centos, making an alias didn't work

Tags: centos, software-installation, python, configure, llvm

I am trying to install llvm on my centos 6.7. 
While running the configure file it says it throws the error

> checking for python >= 2.7... not found 
>   configure: error: found python
>   2.6.6 (/usr/bin/python); required >= 2.7 See `config.log' for more details.

So I installed python 2.7, but since the previous python version is already in there the configure shows the same error. I tried aliasing python with the new python version using

> alias python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7

This made python2.7 to be executed while calling python. But the error while running the configure file is still there. How can I resolve this.

Comment: llvm (i.e.. clang and friends) are available in [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL). No need to compile by hand.

Comment: How did you install the new python? (`Yum` will often remove the old package, but if you used `rpm` it might have left the old package around to cause your issues). Also, as @vonbrand said, you should just be able to use your package manager to do the install.

Comment: @darklion build python from the source. yum wont install python to the latest version

Comment: Download a more recent version of Python and then change your Path or PythonPath to point to that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want Python 2.7 on a CentOS6 system, install the [Python 2.7 Software Collection](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/python27/) package.  It will not replace /usr/bin/python, but if you load the python27 scl, `configure` will detect it.

*Note:  you should just use the EPEL package for llvm if that's all you want.*

Answer (score -2):

First remove the symbolic link of existing python using

> sudo rm -r /usr/bin/python

Then create a new link to python for python-2.7

> sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python

Comment: This will break your CentOS system.  If you replace /usr/bin/python with something you built in /usr/local, your system will never be able to run 'yum' and you will cease to get any software updates and security fixes.